# Devolver varios indices de un array en Swift 4

Tags: array, ios, swift4

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo obtener varios índices dentro de un *array* de cadenas o caracteres.

Un ejemplo:

```
var arrayInput = ["2","+","3","(","2","-","4","(","3","*","5",")",")",]

func isParentheses() {
    var count = 0
    var arrayNumParentesis:Array<String> = []

    for x in arrayInput {
        if x == "(",
            let index = arrayInput.index(of: x) {
                let y = index
                arrayNumParentesis.append(y)
                print(arrayNumParentesis)

        }
    }
}
```

Intento introducir los valores de la posición en el *array* de los caracteres de apertura de paréntesis pero como podréis comprobar se guarda solamente el valor del primero.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema en tu código parece ser cuando haces:

```
let index = arrayInput.index(of: x)
```

porque siempre devuelve el índice del primer paréntesis en el *array*.

La solución en este caso sería iterar sobre los índices y no sobre los elementos del *array*:

```
for i in 0..<arrayInput.count {
    if arrayInput[i] == "(" {
        arrayNumParentesis.append(i)
    }
}
print(arrayNumParentesis)
```

Sin embargo, haciéndolo así tendrías que implementarlo para cada valor que quieras buscar. El paréntesis debería ser un parámetro de tu función.

De hecho, obtener los índices de una lista con elementos repetidos parece ser algo que se podría aplicar a cualquier *array* (siempre que sus elementos sean comparables). Una solución más genérica sería extender el tipo de datos `Array`. Algo así:

```
extension Array where Array.Element: Equatable {
    func indexesOf(_ item: Element) -> [Int] {
        var result: [Int] = []
        for i in 0..<self.count {
            if self[i] == item {
                result.append(i)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

y luego obtienes los índices con:

```
let p = arrayInput.indexesOf("(")
print(p)
```

El resultado en tu ejemplo es:

```
[3, 7]
```